# multiple gcc versions in makefile

Tags: c++, gcc, makefile, compiler-version

In my Makefile I have

```
CC=g++
```

When I do mgrep gcc, I have several versions listed like:
gnu/gcc/4.2.1
gnu/gcc/4.7.3
etc

I can do a module load to change my gcc version.

Now suppose I want to use multiple versions simultaneously in different makefiles, how do I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The module system is basically just setting up a path to the requested module. If you want a particular compiler in a particular makefile, then you can do three things:

1. Expect the user of the makefile to load the correct version before calling Make. Possibly combined with some condition based on `gcc -v|grep ${GCC_VERSION}` to check that it's the right version.
2. Perform `module load gnu/gcc/${GCC_VERSION}` inside your makefile.
3. Use `CC=/somewhere/path-to-gcc-version/bin/g++` instead of `CC=g++`.

Personally, I prefer 1 or 3. You can find out what the path is by doing `module load ...` and then `which g++`.

[By the way, I would use `CXX=g++` and `CC=gcc` - assuming you are not compiling files called `*.c` as C++-code]

Comment: I tried method 3. 'which gcc' gave /A/B/C/D/bin/gcc. So I tried CC=/A/B/C/D/bin/gcc. I got an error. make:/A/B/C/D/bin/gcc : Command not found

Comment: sorry, I was making a typo.